# "Fetch entity by property" for multi-value term reference field

Tags: rules

Node A and user both have a term reference field which referenced to the same vocabulary,  the term reference field of Node A is single-value, but that of user is multi-value.

I created a rule: after saving a new Node A , Fetch entity by property, the Entity type is User, the Property is the multi-value term reference field, but I cannot select the single-value field in the node, the page hints the property value should be "Data types: Select data of the type *List of taxonomy term items*." When I select "node:field-problem-category" (the single-value term reference field) and save, the page shows error: The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's value requirement. I have to select node:field-problem-category:parent. But thus no entity can be fetched.

I followed the instruction [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108763/rules-fetch-entity-by-property-for-users-that-share-terms-with-new-node), but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

BTW:It will be best that the "Fetch entity by property" can provide an operator like PHP function *in_array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I solved this problem using [Views Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules), just set the Data type of the Rules parameters (providing to contextual filter) to Text. Then add a view loop in the rule action. A view's multi-value field contextual filter can have only one value.